# Possessive-gerund/ sentence structure

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds, gerunds-vs-participles

Here's an alternative/clearer version of my original question:

Consider the following sentence:

> Instead of his being stationed on a plank, I want him on a pedestal.

This shows the possessive gerund. However, the "I want him..." being juxtaposed with "his being..." seems awkward (as was pointed out in the ensuing comment section).

It is the stationing that I want to discuss. So, to make it less awkward, instead of using "him" for the subject, since we are using "being stationed" as a noun in the first part, can we use a pronoun for it in the second part?

In other words, can I make the sentence

> Instead of his being stationed on a plank, I want [his being stationed] on a pedestal.

where the [text] is replaced by a pronoun (and appropriate grammatical changes).

Is an alternative path better (and what)?

ORIGINAL:

I was writing a question in a different Stack Exchange site and had a doubt about my sentence structure. This is what I typed:

> instead of its being defined on an interval [maths], its definition is on an  interval [maths]

The first part of the sentence shows the possessive-gerund. I was wondering if I could restructure this sentence as

> instead of its being defined on an interval [maths], I want *it* on an interval [maths]/*it* is on an interval [maths]

where *it* refers to the "being-defined"-ness? The reason behind my asking this question is that the reason we use the possessive form is because we are discussing the particular characteristic ("being-defined"-ness) of the subject under scrutiny, so in the next part of the sentence, can we use *it* to refer to the characteristic without ambiguity? Or can *it* be confused for the subject? Or does using *it* make sense only when it is referring to the subject (which makes the most sense to me).

To be honest, using "its definition" in the sentence I originally typed also sounds a little weird to me (I was going to put in "I want it to be defined on..." instead), but I do think that it grammatically agrees with "its being defined".

Ultimately, what I am asking is if "being defined" may be used *exactly* as a  noun might. Because the second sentence certainly makes perfect sense if I had used "definition" instead of "being defined" (with the necessary grammatical changes).

Comment: I am totally fine with *its being defined on an interval*, and less comfortable with *its definition is on an interval*; the latter sounds too locative (i.e. literal) for my taste. Maybe "its definition applies to an interval*?

Comment: *I don't like **him** [noun], and I don't like **being defined by him** [noun phrase].* No syntactic problems there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers just to make sure I understand, I _can_ use it exactly as a noun and, therefore, I _can_ use the sentence structure I highlighted as an alternative? Just that it does feel a little awkward to my ear.

Comment: @DanBron That actually describes my problem with it pretty well (and you actually put it into words, unlike me), though I do think that it is grammatically correct?

Comment: @radm94: I don't really understand *defined on an interval* in your example, but syntactically it's fine to use a gerund (or gerund-based phrase) as a noun. Essentially, the *definition* of a gerund is *continuous verb form **functioning as a noun***. So me saying this *isn't* a gerund, but ***my*** saying it is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I constructed a sentence which is similar: "Instead of his being stationed on a plank, I want him on a pedestal". Here, we cannot put "it" instead of "him". (The original sentence was about the location of a function). So, that clears my doubt, I guess. But, also, what if I want to talk about his "being stationed" characteristic in the next part of the sentence, instead of writing "him"? (Is discussing this a futile endeavour?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers We are using "being stationed" ("being defined") as a noun in the first part, so can we use a pronoun for it in the second part, if it is the stationing (definition) that I want to discuss, instead of the subject?(Is discussing this a futile endeavour?)

Comment: @radm94: Thanks for that alternative. Perhaps you'd get a better response to your *actual* query if you edited to include that in your question text (instead of an example where unfamiliar but irrelevant *semantic* issues may be distracting people from the *syntax*). So far as I'm concerned, your "**his** being stationed" example is perfectly grammatical as a gerund usage. Stylistically I think it's *very* slightly awkward/inelegant to juxtapose ***his** [being somewhere]* with ***him** [being somewhere else]*. I don't think it's  a "futile endeavour", and I'd like to know what others think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sentence can sometimes be made to stand in the position of a noun phrase (NP) by nominalizing it.  There are two nominalized sentences in your example:

```
Instead of his being stationed on a plank, I want him on a pedestal.
```

"his being stationed on a plank" is a *POSS-ing* nominalization of "He is stationed on a plank", and the nominalization is object of the preposition "instead of".  "him on a pedestal" is probably a *FOR-TO* nominalization of "he is on a pedestal" (a more regular form would be ?"for him to be on a pedestal"), and the nominalization is object of the verb "want".

The English nominalization system is quite disorderly.  A general feature of it is that the particular form of nominalization used depends on the function of the nominalization in the larger construction.  In the example, if we were to use a *POSS-ing* nominalization after "want", we'd get the ungrammatical *"I want his being on a pedestal".  Why?  It's just an idiosyncrasy of "want" that it does not allow a following *POSS-ing* nominalization.  Compare the verb "like" which tolerates both kinds of nominalization:

```
I like him on a pedestal.  
I like his being on a pedestal.
```

Classifying the *-ing* form of the verb in *POSS-ing* nominalizations as a *gerund* is not at all helpful in analyzing them, since this verb form has verbal properties and no nominal properties whatsoever within the sentence that has been nominalized.